# From where I can get ncurses wgetch source code?

Tags: ncurses

I looked up into ncurses code from https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz and https://github.com/gittup/ncurses/ to search for a wgetch definition, but it seems this function is external, where is it defined?

Comment: [How did you miss it](https://github.com/gittup/ncurses/blob/gittup/ncurses/base/lib_getch.c#L550)? A simple `grep -r` was not enough?

Comment: Thanks that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

in that case, "extern" is a linkage modifier, a hint to the compiler about where the symbol referred to afterwards is defined (the hint is, "not here").
so the wgetch symbol usually comes in the ncurses library/shared object (libncurses.so under linux for example")

Comment: I know its for exporting, but didn't find the actual definition in the codebase